# different output with mono on linux as on visual studio on win7 with calling a webservice

Tags: web-services, f#, mono

I use the Exchange webservices to extract attachments from exchange mailserver.
When i call the code on linux with mono a certain text attachment contain some mixed-up strings.

like so

"sam winglin vz" becomes "sainglin vz" -> so it is missing "m w".
I see this about 3 times in a 150kb file. 3 bytes are missing in the linux output vs the windows output.

When i extract it from visual studio the text attachment is perfect.

It is like this example
[Save attachments from exchange inbox](http://fssnip.net/aF)

Any idea in what direction i should look to fix this?

Code:

```
#r "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"

open Microsoft
open Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data
open System
open System.Net

type PgzExchangeService(url,user,password) =
    let service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1,
                                      TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("Central Standard Time",new TimeSpan(-6, 0, 0),"(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)","Central Standard Time"))


    do
       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback <- ( fun _ _ _ _ -> true )
       service.Url <- new Uri(url)
       service.Credentials <- new WebCredentials(user, password, "domain")

    member this.Service with get() = service
    member this.InboxItems = this.Service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10))
    member this.GetFileAttachments ( item : Item ) =        
           let emailMessage = 
               EmailMessage.Bind( this.Service, 
                                  item.Id, 
                                  new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly,    ItemSchema.Attachments))
           item, emailMessage.Attachments |> Seq.choose (fun attachment -> match box attachment with  
                                                                       | :? FileAttachment as x -> Some(x) | _ -> None)   

let mailAtdomain = new PgzExchangeService("https://xx.xx.XX.XX/EWS/Exchange.asmx", "user", "passw")

let printsave (item : Item ,att : seq<FileAttachment>) =
    if (Seq.length att) > 0 then
        printfn "%A - saving %i attachments" item.Subject (Seq.length att)        
        att |> Seq.iter ( fun attachment -> printfn "%A" attachment.Name 
                                            attachment.Load(@"/tmp/test/" + attachment.Name ) )   

// filter so we only have items with attachements and ...
let itemsWithAttachments = mailAtdomain.InboxItems                            
                           |> Seq.map mailAtdomain.GetFileAttachments 
                           |> Seq.iter printsave
```

The code doesn't run on Windows with mono due to a bug in TimeZoneInfo

---

This sample code runs on linux but not on windows. because of the TimeZoneInfo bug.
But with this the code that works on linux to extract attachments.
Try csv attachments and see if the result is the same. i loose data ! about 3 bytes every somemany lines

mail me if you need the sample csv attachment that gives the problem

Here is a c# version that i used for testing. Running from VS2010 it works perfect but on linux with mono the attachment has wrong size , some bytes are missing?!.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using System.Net;

namespace Exchange_SDP_Attachment_Extracter
{
    public class PgzExchangeService
    {
        public void Extract()
        {            
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService  (ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1,TimeZoneInfo.Local);
            service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain");
            service.Url = new Uri("https://xx.xx.xx.xx/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));
            foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
            {
                EmailMessage e = EmailMessage.Bind
                                 (service,
                                   item.Id,
                                   new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));
                foreach ( Attachment att in e.Attachments )
                {

                    if (att is FileAttachment)
                    {
                        FileAttachment fileAttachment = (FileAttachment)att;
                        fileAttachment.Load(@"/tmp/testsdp/" + fileAttachment.Name);                        
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             PgzExchangeService pgz = new PgzExchangeService();
             pgz.Extract();
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: Is your code "like this example" or is it exactly the same?  If it's exactly the same then say so and if it isn't, it'd be hard to figure out this error without seeing your exact code.  Also need to know: version of Mono, version of F#, version of exchange etc. etc.

Comment: The example is a simple version of my real program but the extraction of the attachment comes down to the webservice call of attachment.load. This seems to function different between linux and windows. version of mono = 2.8 and f# 2.0

Comment: What happens if you try Mono on Windows?

Comment: Why not post your actual code - or at least a simplified version which exhibits the problem?

Comment: I try to run it on windows but ran into this TimeZoneInfo bug that exists in the windows mono version. [Bug 622524 - Calling TimeZoneInfo.Local throws TimeZoneNotFoundException](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=622524)

Comment: You probably should edit the question to reflect the fact that you can reproduce this in C# as well.  Probably most folks aren't reading all these comments and the comments on my answer--just reading your question.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to try examining the text attachment with a hex editor.  There has be something unusual about those three occurrences.  You need to find out what those three lines have in common before any of us can recommend a course of action to you.

Comment: I made a c# version and did a build from VS 2010 and ran the exe on linux and this gave the same result. It works flawless on windows but is wrong on linux

Comment: All the more reason to look at the attachment itself.  Those three items must contain some character (or characters) that are causing a problem on Linux.  You need to figure out what that character or characters are.

Comment: there are 2 cases. 3 bytes missing , always alphanumeric data but no logic. Or 4 bytes replaced by 1 byte, numeric data. also no logic

Comment: "sam winglin" becomes "sainglin" ( "m w" replaced by "" )

Comment: Create another _new_ attachment on the linux box with the same strings in it.  If the problem occurs again then it's something about the text.  If the problem doesn't occur then it's something about the file itself.  BTW, I'm not unpaid tech support--I'm happy to offer you suggestions but ultimately I can't fix your problems for you.  If you're not willing to check the file with a hex editor to see if there are hidden characters don't expect me (or anyone else here) to do your work for you.

Comment: i will check it for hidden character but if it works on windows/.net and not on linux/mono then i think that mono is the problem

Comment: You've isolated a reproducible test case; your next step is to submit it to the Mono folks and get their comments on it.

Comment: One more thing you might try--try creating an attachment with just the four lines you reference and nothing else.  If you still see the problem with just those four lines then you've indeed hit upon some odd corner case.  Otherwise, it's likely to be something else about the file itself.

Comment: Some more experimenting. The file contains the error exact after 8192 bytes ( 8 k ) and again after the next 8k at byte 16384.

Comment: And that's what I'd submit to the Mono folks.  Most likely they'll need to fix it and now that you've isolated a direct repro case like that--well they may even already have caught the problem and they may already have a fix for it.